# Add inline image in Rmarkdown

Tags: markdown, rstudio, r-markdown, pandoc

I can't find a way to insert an inline image on a markdown document I'm producing with RStudio.

Seems like the RmarkDown Style Cheat sheet `(https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/rmarkdown-cheatsheet-2.0.pdf)` does not mention such feature.

Is this currently possible?

Here's an example using html for a svg image:
`link: http://www.herongyang.com/HTML/HTML5-Add-Inline-SVG-Image-HTML5-Documents.html`

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with 'inline image'?

Comment: @J_F example: inserting a small flag image after country_name: `http://www.herongyang.com/HTML/HTML5-Add-Inline-SVG-Image-HTML5-Documents.html`. I want this image to be part of the text, inside a paragraph. Clear as mud?

Comment: @mb21 I've updated my packages and `foo ![]() bar` now works. I was probably doing somehting stupid. Do you want to add this answer and I'll accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Markdown syntax allows inline images:

```
foo ![](image.png) bar
```

Comment: Trick: use &nbsp; to get a centered inline image.

Answer (score 6):

Could also use the display property

```
![](images.png?display=inline-block)
```

Comment: interesting addition, Qing. Thanks!

Comment: I found this thread when trying to do the same: adding an inline image. Don't know why but the `foo ![]() bar` doesn't work for me. Stayed with html for some time, i.e., `<img src="/image" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0" />`. Only recently stumbled upon this solution. Hope it helps.